# Is it possible to call a function that is not in the path in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab

I have installed a library that has some functions with the same name as MATLAB's. And by installing the lib, I mean addpath. When I try to call those function it'll use that lib's implementation but I want to call MATLAB implementation.

To make it simpler: how can I specify which function to call given that I have the absolute address of both functions?

I searched for the answer but I didn't find it on the website.

Comment: How big is the library, and how much work are you going to be doing with it? How often do you want to call its functions from your code? Is there OO code in the library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you overload any of the MATLAB built-in functions to handle a specific class, then MATLAB always calls the overloaded function on that type. If, for some reason, you need to call the built-in version, you can override the usual calling mechanism using the builtin function. The expression

```
builtin('reshape', arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

forces a call to the MATLAB built-in function, reshape, passing the arguments shown even though an overload exists for the class in this argument list.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br65lhj-1.html

Answer (score 8):

use `run`, it will allow you to use your own functions instead of built-ins *without* adding them to the path.

Taken from help:

> Run script that is not on current path
>   Syntax
>
> run scriptname

As @Cheery correctly said, it cannot be used for functions that accept arguments. However, `run.m` is modifiable file, so I made an extended version, that can accept arguments. It can be modified for output arguments as well quite easily.

```
function runExtended(script,varargin)

    cur = cd;

    if isempty(script), return, end
    if ispc, script(script=='/')='\'; end
    [p,s,ext] = fileparts(script);
    if ~isempty(p),
        if exist(p,'dir'),
            cd(p)
            w = which(s);
            if ~isempty(w),
                % Check to make sure everything matches
                [wp,ws,wext] = fileparts(w);
                % Allow users to choose the .m file and run a .p
                if strcmp(wext,'.p') && strcmp(ext,'.m'),
                    wext = '.m';
                end

                if ispc
                    cont = ~strcmpi(wp,pwd) | ~strcmpi(ws,s) | ...
                        (~isempty(ext) & ~strcmpi(wext,ext));
                else
                    cont = ~isequal(wp,pwd) | ~isequal(ws,s) | ...
                        (~isempty(ext) & ~isequal(wext,ext));
                end
                if cont
                    if exist([s ext],'file')
                        cd(cur)
                        rehash;
                        error('MATLAB:run:CannotExecute','Can''t run %s.',[s ext]);
                    else
                        cd(cur)
                        rehash;
                        error('MATLAB:run:FileNotFound','Can''t find %s.',[s ext]);
                    end
                end
                try
                    feval(s,varargin{:});
                    %           evalin('caller', [s ';']);
                catch e
                    cd(cur);
                    rethrow(e);
                end
            else
                cd(cur)
                rehash;
                error('MATLAB:run:FileNotFound','%s not found.',script)
            end
            cd(cur)
            rehash;
        else
            error('MATLAB:run:FileNotFound','%s not found.',script)
        end
    else
        if exist(script,'file')
            evalin('caller',[script ';']);
        else
            error('MATLAB:run:FileNotFound','%s not found.',script)
        end
    end

end
```

Comment: it is for the SCRIPTS, not for the functions! did you try it? you will not able to supply function arguments this way. and the result of this call for the function file will be something like this `??? Input argument "x" is undefined.` where "x" is an argument of the function.

Comment: Of course. Try this - function file `function y = myfunc(x) (new line is here)
y = x;
disp(y);` save it as `myfunc.m` somewhere and try `run path/myfunc.m` in the Matlab's command line. The result will be `??? Input argument "x" is undefined.` Matlab has two types of the files - for functions and for the scripts. You can not run function file directly from the editor or command line. Function file should be in the path and Matlab will try to locate it by itself at the call.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to your question which I like when I'll be calling a lot of the built-in functions in a row is to move my library to the end of the path temporarily.

```
libpath = '/home/user/mylib';
% move mylib to the end of the path
addpath(libpath, '-end');
% now call some built-in functions that mylib overwrites
reshape(rand(100),10,10);
% return mylib to the top
addpath(libpath)
```

Of course if you use the built-in functions more often than your libary's, you could keep the library at the end of the path and move it to the top whenever you use it. Be careful about your current directory, however, it will always take [precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-58170.html#bresuvu-6) over the path order.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's answer is not ideal for me, but it and Loren's suggestion to "cd to the directory, create
your function handle, and then cd back" made me think of the following:

Define a function that does what Loren describes:

```
function functionHandle = getFunctionHandleFromFile( fullFileName )

[pathstr, name, ext] = fileparts(fullFileName);

prevDir = pwd;

cd(pathstr);
functionHandle = str2func(name);
cd(prevDir);
```

Then you can just use that to get the handle.  With the handle, you can invoke the function:

```
nameOf = getFunctionHandleFromFile('/Users/sage/matlab-utilities/nameOf.m')
nameOf(output)
```

Note to newer MATLAB users: I recommend caution with this approach!  It can be very helpful in certain circumstances, but in general I'd ask myself if there's not a better way to deal with the problem you are trying to solve.  This could create more headaches than it solves.

Comment: The problem is when the function wants to read/write a file from/to current working directory, your method breaks.

Comment: See also related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072470/call-a-function-that-is-not-on-the-matlab-path-without-adding-that-path/22532918#22532918 and  FEX Contribution: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45941-constructor-for-functionhandles