# Call a Matlab function not in working directory

Tags: matlab, directory

Is it possible to have Matlab call a function that is not in the working folder?
For example, can I specify a path like `.\bar\foo(arg1)` and have the function execute? I have a number of helper functions that I want to use without clogging up my working directory.

Comment: Maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072470/call-a-function-that-is-not-on-the-matlab-path-without-adding-that-path

Comment: `addpath` is what you want. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the command `addpath` to add the folders you need to the MATLAB path.