# How to call function that is being shadowed by another one earlier in the MATLAB search path?

Tags: matlab

By way of preamble, consider this example from Unix.  Suppose that `/some/path/foo` and `/some/other/path/foo` are both available executables.  Also, suppose that both `/some/path` and `/some/other/path` are present in the `$PATH` environment variable, with `/some/path` appearing first.  Then, if I run

```
% foo
```

the `foo` that gets run is `/some/path/foo`.  That's what the `$PATH` variable is all about.

*Nevertheless*, I can always invoke the other `foo` by referring to it by its full path, like this:

```
% /some/other/path/foo
```

IOW, once I refer to the command by its full path, no name resolution needs to happen, so `$PATH` plays no role in deciding which `foo` gets run.

Importantly, this mechanism does not require modifiying the `$PATH` variable.  One just sidesteps it.

---

With this example in mind, does MATLAB provide a way (other than changing the search path) to run a function `foo` from a file different from the first candidate file in the MATLAB search path?

Comment: Have you seen [`userpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/userpath.html) ?

Comment: See MATLAB's [function precedence order](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html). The simplest option is to [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) to the path of the desired function or script. MATLAB's [`run`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html) is a thin wrapper for this to use on scripts.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072470/call-a-function-that-is-not-on-the-matlab-path-without-adding-that-path and a way to call a function that is not in the path.

Answer (score 0):

See MATLAB [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) and [feval](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html).